# React Rails : How to get the results of an API Call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I need the result of an api call to another server for a react component: let's say for now I just need to display either true or false as text

I have the following component:

//   some_random_thing.coffee

```
    { div, h5 } = DOM
    actions = require '../../actions'
    
    class MfaQRCode extends React.Component
      @propTypes: {}
    
    
      constructor: ->
        super arguments...
        @validationTimeout = null
  shouldComponentUpdate: -> true

  render:->
    div {},
      @renderStatus()

  renderStatus: ->
    h5 {className: 'column-header'},
      "BOOLEAN::"
        @props.resource.boolean_record
```

Which is a child component of something else;
Then to populate this boolean_record I have in my actions.coffee file

```
    api = require('./api')
    AddUserPopupActions = ReactUtils.actions.creators.popup
      somethingExists: { asyncResult: true }

AddUserPopupActions.somethingExists.listen ->
  @promise(api.somethingExists(arguments...))
```

In api.coffee

```
    api = ReactUtils.api
    
    class Api
    
    somethingExists: ->
      api.get "/servers/users/something/exists"
```

This get request is handled in a rails controller which I believe to be fine. My question is, how can I populate a variable so that I can use the result of the request which returns true or false from another server.

There is a method in a file named store.coffee where the resource component of props is populated I need to populate this with the result of the api request: have tried:

```
  onSomethingExists: (response) ->   
    @resource.boolean_record = response.responseJSON.result   
    @_update()
```

But this method is not getting triggered at all it seems upon debugging. I'm very new to react and do not fully understand how it all works and given the fact coffeescript and rails are in the mix there is little information to be found on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using refluxjs
If this is the case, your store should be listening to your actions.

```
onSomethingExists: (response) ->
```

This is called when the somethingExists method is called, but the arguments are what you pass to the somethingExists function.

You need to add two more functions in your store to handle successful / error result to your request:

```
onSomethingExistsCompleted: (response) ->   
  console.log "onSomethingExistsCompleted", response

onSomethingExistsFailed: (response) ->   
  console.log "onSomethingExistsCompleted", response
```

To get values from this into your react view, you will need to use `setState` in the store, and then it should arrive in the view on `@state` given that said view is connected to the store